# Write a Program that calculates the sum of (a/1)+(a/2)+(a/3)+(a/4)+..........+(a/n)

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to solve this program its to Print the sum of: (a/1)+(a/2)+(a/3)+(a/4)+..........+(a/n)
where a is inputed by the user and the limit for n is also inputed by the user this is the program i tried:

```
/**
 * Program to 
 * 
 * Anirudh Gupta
 * th August 2014
 */
import java.io.*;
public class Program87b
{
   public static void main () throws IOException
   {
       InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(isr);
       System.out.println("Enter the value of the numerator");
       double a=Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
       System.out.println("Enter the limit for the denominator");
       int limit=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
       double n=1.0;
       double sum=0.0;
       while(n<=limit)
       {
           sum=+(a/n);
           n++;
       }
       System.out.println(sum);
   }
}
```

but when i enter a=4 and n=5 i get 0.8 which is just the ans of (4/5) and not the sum of (4/1)+(4/2)+(4/3)+(4/4)+(4/5) which should be 9.1333333333...

Comment: Change `=+` to `+=`.

Comment: What is `d`?  I don't see it defined anywhere so I'm not sure how that program even runs.

Comment: oh sorry just changed it... still dosen't work and =+ and += are the same so idk how it will make a difference

Comment: No, `=+` and `+=` are not the same.

Comment: oh @DavidWallace what is the difference?

Comment: The one that works means what you think it means.  The one that doesn't doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change =+ to += and I wasn't sure where the variable 'd' came from, but I believe it should be replaced with 'n'

```
public static void main () throws IOException
   {
       InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(isr);

       System.out.println("Enter the value of the numerator");
       double a=Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());

       System.out.println("Enter the limit for the denominator");
       int limit=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

       double n=1.0;
       double sum=0.0;

       while(n<=limit)
       {
           sum+=(a/n);
           n++;
       }

       System.out.println(sum);
   }
```

Comment: thanks i got it from ur snippet but i did the same thing as u did: this was my original 1 and i dont see a difference:

System.out.println("Enter the value of the numerator");
double n=Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
      
System.out.println("Enter the limit for the denominator");
int limit=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
     
double d=1.0;
double sum=0.0;
while(d<=limit)
{
       sum=+(n/d);
       d++;
}
       
  System.out.println(sum);

Comment: The difference from your original was the change from =+ to +=

Comment: OH MY GOSH THANK YOU!!! I THOUGHT += AND =+ ARE THE SAME!! (ARE THEY?!) BUT ANYWAY THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: a += b is the same as a = a + b, a =+ b is the same as a = b

Comment: but what is the point of the + then in the a=+b... I'm actually a noob at this so a+=b is a=a+b and a=+b is a=b rite?!

Comment: There is no point, it's like saying a equals positive b, just like if you said a = -b would be a equals negative b

Comment: oh! thanks... now i get it so it just takes the positive value of b and if b was -4 the value of a would be +4... thanks...

Comment: @Anirudh No, if you write `a = +b` and `b` would be `-4`, then `a` would also be `-4`. You don't take the positive value, you just take the value. So `a = +b` is the same as `a = b`.

Answer (score 1):

This gave your expected output:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Sum
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
       InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(isr);
       System.out.println("Enter the value of the numerator");
       double a=Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
       System.out.println("Enter the limit for the denominator");
       int limit=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
       double n=1.0;
       double sum=0.0;
       while(n<=limit)
       {
           sum+=(a/n);
           n++;
       }
       System.out.println(sum);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error was coming from  this line `sum =+ (a/n);`, it should be `sum += (a/n);`.  Also you have some extra variables that you do not need, so I would modify your code to something similar to this:

```
public static void main () throws IOException {
     BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

     System.out.println("Enter the value of the numerator");
     double a=Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());

     System.out.println("Enter the limit for the denominator");
     int limit=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

     double sum = 0.0;
     for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
          sum += a / i;
     }

     System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Note: You can also use the `java.util.Scanner` class instead of `java.io.BuferedReader` if you want to make the code even more readable:

```
 public static void main () {

         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.println("Enter the value of the numerator");
         double a = in.nextDouble();

         System.out.println("Enter the limit for the denominator");
         int limit= in.nextInt();

         double sum = 0.0;
         for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
              sum += a / i;
         }

         System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

Comment: @Anirudh your welcome, note that in composition operators like `+=`
 the operators( `+ - * /`) usually fall before the `=` in java, and many other languages: `+=`, `-=`, `*=` and `/=`.

Comment: @Anirudh also note some of the readability changes I made to your code in my answer.  If this is for a school assignment you want to make sure that the graders can clearly read your code, and make sure to comment (`//Comments look like this in case you needed to know`).

Comment: yea.. but i had to do this in "do-while" but since i was getting an error i changed it to "while" and now i can change it back to "do-while" since both are similar... i actually prefer "for" but our teacher wanted us to do it in do-while.... thanks for the tip... will add it to my programs.

Comment: and i'm not allowed to use java.util.Scanner (though i know how to use it) as my teacher would be pissed that i used something she hasn't thought

Comment: If you have to use a `do-while` then you can do this: `do { sum += a / i--; } while (i > 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence looks a lot like a [Harmonic Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) `a*Hn` You  may want to use the [approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496116/is-there-a-partial-sum-formula-for-the-harmonic-series) if accuracy is not an issue